# Why don't pictures align vertically?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, diagrams

I want to align cell content (any) vertically. But at first - it doesn't work with pictures. Why? and how to fix it?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{L{0.5\textwidth}l} 
\includegraphics[width=25pt, height=25pt]{pic1.png} &  
\includegraphics[width=150pt, height=150pt]{pic2.png}\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

UPD: 
for the text aligment i use

```
\newcolumntype{R}[2]{>{ \raggedleft \arraybackslash \hspace{0pt}}{#2}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[2]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}{#2}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[2]{>{\center\arraybackslash}{#2}{#1}}
```

But when I put

```
\begin{tabular}{L{0.5\textwidth}{p}L{100mm}{m}}
bla-bla & \includegraphics[width=25pt, height=25pt, valign=c]{pic0.png}
```

it doesn't align the second column content in the middle of the cell, what is the trick?

I need a common rule due to generate tex automaticly

Comment: Welcome! Please make your code compilable. It'll never work like that :(. Also, what is wrong with the result. You've asked for them to be aligned left. Also, never use `\\ ` like that. It should be used outside of environments such as `tabular` and `array`. (Using it inside would be fine.)

Comment: @cfr thanks for the comment! i put full code, compilable

Comment: @crf - result is - first image aligned by bottom verticaly, i need middle or top aligment

Comment: When I create an example with the lines you give in the update, the picture on the right is centre-aligned vertically. Why do you think it is not aligned in the middle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer. You already have answers. It is, rather, an attempt to explain the basis of those answers.

Here's a picture:

[image: baseline alignment]

The blue dashed line shows the baseline of the first column, which is the baseline of the text. Note that the bulk of the text protrudes above this baseline, but parts of some characters protrude below the baseline.

The magenta dotted line shows the baseline of the second column, which is the baseline of the image. The `valign=c` adjusts the image so that the centre of the image is vertically aligned with the centre of a lower-case character with neither descenders nor ascenders (e.g. 'x' is normally such a character, whereas 'y' and 'h' normally are not) in the current font size. See the diagram on page 13 of the `adjustbox` manual for further details.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\newenvironment{this}{\Huge}{\par}
\standaloneenv{this}
\usepackage{array,tikz}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\newcolumntype{L}[2]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}{#2}{#1}}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{this}
  \tikzmark{a}%
  \begin{tabular}{L{0.5\textwidth}{p}L{100mm}{m}}
    \tikzmark{b}bla-bla piety & \includegraphics[width=50pt, height=50pt, valign=m]{example-image-a}\tikzmark{c}\\
  \end{tabular}%
  \tikzmark{d}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, font=\normalsize, inner sep=0pt]
    \foreach \i in {a,...,d} \coordinate (\i) at (pic cs:\i);
    \draw [blue, densely dashed] (a |- b) -- (d |- b) node [pos=.65, above] {column 1 baseline};
    \draw [magenta, densely dotted] (a |- c) -- (d |- c) node [pos=.85, above] {column 2 baseline};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{this}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The reference point for pictures is always the bottom left; using `m` will not do. You can use `adjustbox` instead.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\includegraphics[width=25pt, height=25pt, valign=t]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=90pt, height=90pt, valign=t]{example-image-b} \\
\includegraphics[width=25pt, height=25pt, valign=c]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=90pt, height=90pt, valign=c]{example-image-b} \\
\includegraphics[width=25pt, height=25pt, valign=b]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=90pt, height=90pt, valign=b]{example-image-b} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So it's nesessary to process text cells and image cells - in a different way?

Comment: it doesn't work in connection with my columns (see the question upd)

Answer (score 2):

You need a p-column type and not an m-column if you want to align at the top. And then -- as pictures have their baseline at the bottom -- you need to "push" them below the baseline. In the p-column cell this can be done with \vspace{0pt}, in the l-column you can use \raisebox:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{L{0.5\textwidth}l}    
 \vspace{0pt}
 \includegraphics[width=25pt, height=25pt]{example-image} &
 \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=150pt, height=150pt]{example-image}}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: figure alignment]

Comment: I'm generating tex doc automaticly, and i need a common rule for vertical aligment - how to align pics on the top or middle or bottom - of the cell. Is it possible? See the update of the question

Comment: TeX doesn't align object, is aligns the *baseline*  of objects. The baseline of a graphic is normally at the bottom. You can change this with the adjustbox package, but I can't tell you if this can be automated in your setup.

Comment: so why when i put p-b-m columns alignment - the third one not in the middle? How does this baseline works in this case?

Comment: Sure it is in the middle (but don't forget the depth of lines). Start with normal text in your columns (`Yy\par Yy\par Yy `) to understand alignment, and add large objects like graphics later.